# The android application Crashes

Tags: android, toast

I am absolutely new in android development. I am trying to write a simple android application, which has a button and shows a toast.
I can see the icon in the virtual device, but the app crashes when I click on it.
Following is what I have written so far:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.stringopsapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
//import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "reach Me @ Winscosin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000001"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="@string/MyString"
    android:textColor="#bbcc00"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:onClick="selfDestruct"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="@string/self_destruct" />
```

The Console shows following:

```
[2013-12-15 14:09:10 - StringOpsApp] ------------------------------
[2013-12-15 14:09:10 - StringOpsApp] Android Launch!
[2013-12-15 14:09:10 - StringOpsApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-12-15 14:09:10 - StringOpsApp] Performing com.example.stringopsapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-12-15 14:09:10 - StringOpsApp] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'MyDevice' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2013-12-15 14:09:10 - StringOpsApp] Uploading StringOpsApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-12-15 14:09:14 - StringOpsApp] Installing StringOpsApp.apk...
[2013-12-15 14:09:22 - StringOpsApp] Success!
[2013-12-15 14:09:22 - StringOpsApp] Starting activity com.example.stringopsapp.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-12-15 14:09:25 - StringOpsApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.stringopsapp/.MainActivity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have never initialized your member variable `context` and it is therefore `null`. Since you're in an activity, you can use `MainActivity.this` for a context instead.

Also your main layout does not seem to have a view with id `action_settings`. If that's your actual code, you'd get the crash when starting the app and not when clicking the button.

N.B. When posting question about a crash in Android, always include the exception stacktrace from logcat in the question.

Comment: Yes sir, I meant, it crashes as I click on the app icon, It never went into the app

Comment: I added `android:id="@+id/action_settings"` in activity_main.xml. Now it crashed when I click on the button.

Comment: @SegmentationFault That's the null context issue from the first paragraph in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add id into xml file. You button xml has to have one more line:

```
android:id="@+id/action_settings"
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer by laalto is correct.

The context is null. It is not initialized.
Another way to go about is use `getApplicationContext()` inside the Toast.makeText function

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "reach Me @ Winscosin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```